# Save and Restore Instance

Tags: android

In LogoQuiz game when we enter a correct answer, the answer is displayed and the activity is froen. Whenever we go back to that screen the same is displayed. How is that done? Could anyone provide an example?

```
public class Activity3 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button Hint1;
private Button Hint2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity3);

    Hint1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Hint1);
    Hint2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Hint2);
    Hint1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Hint2.setOnClickListener(this);
    Hint2.setEnabled(false);

    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);

    final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);

    input.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
             if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

            String check = input.getText().toString().replace(" ","");
            if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("good")){


                display.setText("correct");
                input.setEnabled(false);
            } else{
                display.setText("Wrong");
            }
            return true;                        
            }
            return false;}

                    });

    }



@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.Hint1:
        showOneButtonDialog();
        break;
    case R.id.Hint2:
        showTwoButtonDialog();
        break;

}}
private void showOneButtonDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle(" Hint 1 ");
    Hint2.setEnabled(true);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage(" This is your Hint1");
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
private void showTwoButtonDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle(" Hint 2 ");
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("This is your Hint2 ");
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you expand, show some code...

Comment: i have added the code. Now when the user enters good in Edittext.. "correct" will get displayed and i want it to be like that forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should save your instace in SharedPreferences

for example: you need to save your String variable `res` to do so

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivityName.this);

Editor edit1 = remembermepref.edit();
                edit1.putString("result_key",youredittext.getText().toString);
                edit1.commit();
```

To retrieve your result in onCreate() use following:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivityName.this);
String res1 = pref.getString("result_key");
if(res1.eqauls("correct")
{
youredittext.setText("correct");
}
```

Now use your result stored in `res1`,way you want. Most important thing is to check whether you have used same key to restore as well ws store the value in SharedPreference

Hope this helps..

Comment: i have edited my code..i m unable to undestand your point like "Now when the user enters good in Edittext.. "correct" will get displayed and i want it to be like that forever – " what this means?

Comment: i want to save that process permanently.. i.e whenever user comes back to the screen, the corrext has to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity:

```
private String question;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("question", question);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
               question = savedInstanceState.getString(
                "question");
            }

}
```

**Edit:**

As you want to save the string perminately:

Example saving string in shared preferences and retrieve it again anywhere in your app.

```
public class PreferencesData {

    public static void saveString(Context context, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sharedPrefs.edit().putString(key, intValue).commit();
    }

    public static int getString(Context context, String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return sharedPrefs.getString(key, "");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PreferencesData.saveString(context, "mynote", "buy more stuff");
// retrieve
String note = PreferencesData.getString(context, "mynote");
```

Use this to save the string on pause, and recreate it in onCreate, or where ever you need the information

The same method can easily be used for other simple types.

**In your case:**

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    PreferencesData.saveString(this, "answer", input.getText().toString());
    super.onPause();
}
```

And in onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity3);

    Hint1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Hint1);
    Hint2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Hint2);
    Hint1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Hint2.setOnClickListener(this);
    Hint2.setEnabled(false);

    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);

    // set to empty string if no value is saved yet
    input.setText(PreferencesData.getString(this, "answer"));

    ....
}
```

Comment: When ever I come back to the screen, the OnkeyListener has to automatically run and display the result

Comment: Not fair :D answered first (I think), extended the answer to match your code and provided (Again, I think) cleaner solution. Think I deserved the 'correct answer' mark.

Comment: sorry for that but i used the same logic that :D has provided thats why i put it correct, there is no intention to make u feel bad, anyway thanks for answering and supporting  cYrixmorten

Comment: It's fine :D just felt like whining abit :P and no problem. Happy coding